# Silverlight LinqToSql SQL Tracing

Tags: silverlight, linq-to-sql, wcf-ria-services

I am using Silverlight 5.0 with LinqToSQl and WCF RIA Services in my project.
I am trying to figure out how to log Traces of the underlying SQL Statements (to Sql Server), either in debug mode, or log it to a console window, or file. I would need this for all CRUD operations.

All samples online point out to the DataContext.Log property, but I always find its value to be "Nothing", and also, I cannot get to it from the Client side of the project. If possible, I am planning to have a UserInterface to display the actual SQL Statements before proceeding to either retrieve or save data. This will be mainly for debugging purposes.

Is there a way to view the underlying SQL Statements from the client end (using a break point and checking the values in the Immediate window, or something like that)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to log the sql statements executed by your DataContext you need to assign a [TextWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.textwriter.aspx) to the property Log of your DataContext.

Null is the default value of [Log](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.log.aspx) for the DataContext and therefore is logging of commands disabled.

To log the sql statements to the console, you can assign Console.Out to the property.

```
db.Log = Console.Out;
```

If you want to write the log to a file you can assign a [StreamWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx) to the property.

Comment: The DataContext resides in the Domain Service. Each time a method is called on the DomainService, the LOG property has to be set (as it is disconnected from the Client). Also, I tried setting it within a method on the Domain Service and check its value after retrieving data .... it did not contain the SQL Statement in any of its (TextWriter) properties.

Comment: @user2023348 I think you misunderstood. When you assign Console.Out to the Log property all SQL statements are writen to the Output Window of Visual Studio when you run your application in VS. If you use a StreamWriter all statements are written to the file associated to the StreamWriter